# max-height, max-width, keep aspect ratio and prevent CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift)

Tags: css

I have problems figuring out a solution to my CLS errors in my Core Web Vitals.

**Requirements:**

- Image has to keep the correct aspect ratio
- Image has to have a max-width (90px) AND a max-height (45px)
- Image shoulnd't trigger a Cumulative Layout Shift

I can only get two requirements to work but never all three. Is there any way to make all three requirements to work in all modern browsers?

*For all the code examples I am loading the image via JS just to show the CLS effect more clearly.*

**Original Code (CLS):**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector('img').src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/115x100';
}, 500);
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


.logo {
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.logo img {
    max-height: 45px;
    max-width: 90px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.name {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img width="115" height="100">
  </div>
  
  <div class="name">
    Company name
  </div>
</div>
```

**Version 2 (max-width and max-height not both defined):**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector('img').src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/115x100';
}, 500);
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


.logo {
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.logo img {
    max-width: 90px;
    height: auto;
}

.name {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img width="115" height="100">
  </div>
  
  <div class="name">
    Company name
  </div>
</div>
```

**Version 3 (aspect ratio wrong):**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector('img').src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/115x100';
}, 500);
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


.logo {
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.logo img {
   max-height: 45px;
   max-width: 90px;
}

.name {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img width="115" height="100">
  </div>
  
  <div class="name">
    Company name
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works in all modern browsers:

```
.logo {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 45px;
    width: 90px;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```